# Arbitrary number of arguments for system method

Tags: ruby, command

I'd like to pass a command `wget` to Ruby's [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method (the second version, that doesn't pass the command to shell.) However, the number of arguments (websites to download) depends on what the user wants. Is there a way to do something like, pass an array of arguments with an arbitrary number of arguments `[site1 site2 ...]` to this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `*` splat operator in front of an array to expand it when calling a method, including the `system` method.

```
sites = %w< site1 site2 ... >
system 'wget', *sites
```